# How much does it cost to run 24kWh on my diesel generator?

Tags: generator

I've got a [generator](https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200682283_200682283?cm_mmc=Google-pla&utm_source=Google_PLA&utm_medium=Generators%20%3E%20Portable%20Generators&utm_campaign=Pulsar&utm_content=60723&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsrjnrtHW2wIVBMJkCh1w7Av2EAQYASABEgLAqfD_BwE), and I'm wondering since my monthly usage is 719kWh how much would it cost to run the house per day if fuel is $4/gallon?

Comment: A lot depends on generator efficiency. Model and idea of peak vs average load might help.

Comment: it is not possible for us to answer your question .... think about what you are asking .... the answer is easy, but you are the only one that can answer it

Comment: Your monthly electrical usage figure isn't enough for people to answer, you also need the monthly run hours. If the generator runs 24/7, you're using power at a rate of 1 KW according to your question. If you're using power at the rated capacity of 5 KW and running it 20% of the time, you would have the same monthly usage. At 1 KW, you won't use only 20% of the fuel, you'll use substantially more, so the fuel per KWh will be much higher. Jasper's answer is enough to tell you that at half-capacity, fuel costs will be high, but if accuracy is needed, you'll need to add load/run-time figures.

Answer (score 1):

The generator you linked to claims to need 4 gallons of fuel to produce 9.5 hours of power at 2.5 kW, or 23.75 kWh.  That is about 6 kWh per gallon.  At $ 4 per gallon, your fuel cost is about 67 cents per kWh.

In other words, you would spend about $ 16 per day on fuel to average 1 kW.  That cost does not include lubricants, maintenance, depreciation, nor the hassle of refueling the generator on a daily basis.  In most places, this fuel cost is much more than the retail cost of the electricity produced.